# How to launch a coroutine that should never be canceled from a Compose event handler

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I have this composable that represents an "edit data" screen:

```
@Composable
fun EditNodeScreen(
    vm: EditNodeViewModel,
    canceled: () -> Unit,
    accepted: (id: UUID) -> Unit
) {
    // ...
    Button(onClick = {
      val id = vm.save()
      accepted(id)
    }) {
      Text(text = "Save")
    }
}
```

Except, `EditNodeViewModel.save()` is actually a suspend function, so I can't just call it like that.

What I can find says that I should create a coroutine scope with `rememberCoroutineScope()`, then use that to launch a coroutine:

```
onClick = {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        val id = vm.save()
        accepted(id) // side question: do I have to switch back to Main context?
    }
}
```

But the documentation *also* says that this coroutine will be canceled if the composition is detached. I do *not* want to cancel the save process once it is commenced!

Is this still the right thing to do, or is there a better way? Should I use `GlobalScope.launch` perhaps?

Comment: GlobalScope is tied to the lifecycle of the application, which seems correct for an IO operation like this.  I am interested in the VM having suspend functions. I would normally call a method on the VM normally, and let the VM decide on how to handle threading.

Comment: @eimmer I've thought about that too, but then how do I ensure I call the `accepted` callback only after the save operation completes? I would have to pass a continuation callback to the VM method, which is not how I want to write my code.

Comment: It's not my field, but isn't this supposed to be the job of the `WorkManager` APIs?

Comment: Upon completion, the VM would raise some sort of state for the UI to observe.

Comment: why don't you use ViewModelScope or any scope that you pass to ViewModel as parameter and don't expose function of ViewModel as suspending function to Compose? Wrap your suspending function with `launch` and call non suspending from Compose?[For instance like in this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471)

Comment: @Thracian Thank you for the article. But see the second comment on the question for why that isn't my ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to handle an operation that should be completed even if the user navigates away from the screen, use `WorkManager`.

From the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#reliable),

> WorkManager is intended for work that is required to run reliably even
> if the user navigates off a screen, the app exits, or the device
> restarts.

Use [Expedited work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#expedited) to start the task immediately.